# How do I find the request that is downloading a file?

Tags: rest, http, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools, fetch-api

i'm trying to use chrome dev tools network view to find the GET/POST/xhr/fetch/etc that downloads a csv file.

i want to download the data in this table:
https://public.tableau.com/profile/oregon.health.authority.covid.19#!/vizhome/OregonCOVID-19CasesbyZIPCode-SummaryTable/CasesbyZIPCodeSummaryTable?publish=yes

click the download icon at the bottom of the table, select "crosstab", select "csv".  then clear the console and network log.  then hit "download."  this downloads a 20kB csv file, but i can't find the associated request.

i've tried clearing the application storage.  how can i find the proper request to download the file myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably can't see it because it opens in a new tab and closes instantly. Get the download link, open a dev console in an empty tab, paste the download link and you will see the network for the file requested. (For getting the download link you can just go to downloads in Chrome)

Comment: oh ha ha i forgot about the downloads view, thanks :)  the curl request works!  but the url contains what look like uid's for session and key, i'm worried they'll expire eventually.  is there a good way to protect against that?

Comment: yeah, after a while it 410's ("gone").  :(  any way to circumvent?  :)